# How to hide defaul toolbar AppBar

Tags: c#, uwp

After the migrated to UWP from Metro, AppBar possess visible default toolbar.

[image]

after the menu is down it's see this,

[image]

How to hide this black toolbar, when my menu is pull?

```
<Page.TopAppBar>        
    <AppBar x:Name="MainAppBar"
            Background="{StaticResource color_kamsoft_2}"               
            BorderBrush="{StaticResource color_kamsoft_2}"
            ExitDisplayModeOnAccessKeyInvoked="False"
            Tapped="MainAppBar_Tapped">
        <custom:MainTopBar 
                           GoToPatientCardTopBarCommand="{Binding GoToPatientCardTopBarCommand}"
                           GoToActualVisitTopBarCommand="{Binding GoToActualVisitTopBarCommand}"
                           GoToHzichTopBarCommand="{Binding GoToHzichTopBarCommand}"
                           GoToLogOutTopBarCommand="{Binding GoToLogOutTopBarCommand}"
                           GoToReservationTopBarCommand="{Binding GoToReservationTopBarCommand}"
                           SendErrorLoggerCommand="{Binding SendErrorLoggerCommand}"
                           BtPatientCardTopBarIsDisabled="{Binding BtPatientCardTopBarIsDisabled}"
                           BTHzichTopBarIsDisabled="{Binding BTHzichTopBarIsDisabled}"
                           GoToSettingsCommand="{Binding GoToSettingsCommand}"
                           BTSettingsTopBarIsDisabled="{Binding BTSettingsTopBarIsDisabled}"
                           BTReservationIsDisabled="True" />
    </AppBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>
```

Comment: Hi, maybe you can try to set the `Background` of the current page to the same background color as `AppBar`. But if you can provide a minimal reproducible demo, it will be more helpful for us to solve your problem.